# How to change my DI framework from dagger to others without affecting code?

Tags: dagger-2, dagger

Dagger looks like a nice framework for android. But how does it decouple itself from real projects?

If I'm using it in one of my project and I don't want to use it anymore, how to delete it from my project without affecting my code?

Answer (score 1):

Dagger meets the [JSR-330 injection standard](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330), which is a Java specification for dependency injection surfaces. This means that most of the configuration you use for your application—at least, spread across the files in your application—are coded to a Java dependency injection standard and not Dagger itself.

Unless you make use of [`Lazy<T>` injections](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.0/dagger/Lazy.html), you can probably switch out your dependency injection framework only at the very top level, where you define your [`@Component`](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.0/dagger/Component.html) and refer to your [`@Module`](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.0/dagger/Module.html) classes. You can also interconnect Dagger components with non-Dagger DI via [component dependencies](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.0/dagger/Component.html#component-dependencies) and clever uses of modules, or write your own Component and Subcomponent implementations whether or not Dagger annotations are on them. Dagger also packages its annotations and public interfaces in a [separate package from the annotation processor](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.dagger), so you can shift off of Dagger code generation without needing to scrub out the annotations on the exact same day.

Things you'd find in common files:

- `@Inject`, `Provider<T>`, `@Qualifier`, and `@Scope`: [JSR-330  standard](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/package-summary.html). These are the interfaces you should see in files that you make DI-aware, and the custom qualifiers and scopes you use in your application. Common scope `@Singleton` and common qualifier `@Named` are also defined in JSR-330.
- [`@AutoFactory`](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/factory): Dagger's recommended solution for automatically generating Factory interfaces and implementations, but not a part of Dagger. Uses `@Inject` and `Provider<T>` and is designed for consumption in Spring, Guice, and other DI environments as well. In contrast, Guice's solution is to use [`FactoryModuleBuilder`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryModuleBuilder.html), which is reflective and Guice-specific.
- `Lazy<T>`: Dagger-specific interface for a Provider that calculates its value exactly once. You can inject either a `Lazy<T>` or a `Provider<T>` for any T Dagger understands, but unlike the Provider interface itself, Lazy isn't defined in JSR-330. Dagger uses its own.
- [`MembersInjector<T>`](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.11/dagger/MembersInjector.html): Dagger-specific, but not used explicitly very often.

Things that are properly Dagger configuration, separate from your business logic:

- `@Module`, `@Provides`, and `@Binds`: Dagger-specific, because every dependency injection structure uses its own type of configuration. Guice uses Java modules reflectively, and Spring is known for its XML configuration. Remember that well-written `@Provides` methods can be called from any code, including your handwritten code.
- `@CanReleaseReferences` and ReleasableReferenceManager: [Dagger-specific extensions.](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/releasablereferences/CanReleaseReferences.html)
- `@ContributesAndroidInjector`, AndroidInjector, and DispatchingAndroidInjector: [Dagger-specific extensions.](https://google.github.io/dagger/android)
- `@Component` and `@Subcomponent`: Dagger-specific annotations, but because these are defined as *interfaces*, you are free to *implement* them however you'd like, including manually. You might also create an interface that has no Dagger or DI annotations whatsoever, and have your Dagger-annotated interfaces *extend* your non-Dagger-annotated annotations.

Lastly, one sneaky thing that Dagger can do: Dagger writes implementations in adjacent packages to your `@Inject` classes and modules. Consequently, you can (for instance) create objects through Dagger that you couldn't create without writing the `public` Factory that calls the object's package-private `@Inject` constructor. If you wanted to rip out Dagger and hand-write your equivalent constructors, you might find yourself adding `public` to a lot of `@Inject`-annotated methods and fields, or writing a lot of helper classes in those packages where they can access the encapsulated methods and fields themselves.

In short, though you may have Dagger-specific infrastructure at your top level and in some of your packages, Dagger is designed for JSR-330 interoperability and—though you may need a lot of files to get around package-private constructors/fields/methods—you shouldn't have to make deep changes to your classes to switch to handwritten components or other frameworks.

Comment: It's too long...  Anyway... Thank you, Jeff.